# Parallel forms and cohomology of symmetric spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, symmetric-spaces

Let $G/H$ be a compact symmetric space.  Then I believe the following is true:  if $\alpha \in \Omega^k(G/H)$ and $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection, then
$$
(\alpha \text{ is induced by an $\operatorname{Ad} H$ element of $\Lambda^* \mathfrak h^\perp$})  \Leftrightarrow \alpha \text{ is $G$-invariant} \Leftrightarrow \nabla \alpha = 0 \Leftrightarrow \alpha \text{ is harmonic}.
$$
This means the real cohomology of $G/H$ is isomorphic to the space of $\operatorname{Ad} H$ invariant elements of $\Lambda^* \mathfrak h^\perp$, which seems like a reasonable thing to be able to compute.

For what compact symmetric spaces have these been computed explicitly, and where can this sort of thing be found in the literature?

Comment: This is more or less the content of the paper by Chevalley and Eilenberg where they defined Lie algebra cohomology, no?

Comment: See  Section 7.4.2 of these lectures http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned above, an invariant form on G/H is harmonic.  The converse is proved in Helgason's book (1978),  pages 227 and 564.  The case of G itself is a theorem of Hodge.

Answer (score 5):

I think there's some confusion in the question. For example by "Levi-Civita connection" you must really mean some kind of Laplacian. Anyway, your end result about the cohomology of $G/H$ is essentially correct. To help clarify the situation, let's bring in some relative Lie algebra cohomology.

The first basic fact is that a Lie group $G$ acts naturally on the space $\Omega^\ast(G/H)$ of differential forms on $G/H$, where $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$. If $G$ and $H$ are connected, then evaluation at the identity gives an isomorphism from the space $\Omega^\ast(G/H)^G$ of $G$-invariant forms onto the space $C^\ast(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak h)$ of relative Lie algebra cohomology cocycles. This isomorphism descends to an isomorphism between the cohomology of the complex of $G$-invariant forms on $G/H$ and relative Lie algebra cohomology $H^\ast(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak h)$.

Now assume that $G$ is reductive and $H$ maximal compact in $G$ with corresponding Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak h \oplus \mathfrak p$. Then there are natural isomorphisms
$$ C^q(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak h) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak h} (\wedge^q \mathfrak p, \mathbb R) = (\wedge^q \mathfrak p)^{\mathfrak h}, $$
where $\mathfrak h$ is acting via the adjoint representation. If you want, this can be rephrased in terms of the action of $H$, and moreover it's possible to introduce a bilinear form so that the above isomorphisms yield
$$ C^q(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak h) = (\wedge^q \mathfrak h^\perp)^H. $$
The next key result is that the differential of this complex is zero, whence
$$ H^q(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak h) = (\wedge^q \mathfrak h^\perp)^H. $$
In some precise sense this is a manifestation of a theorem of E. Cartan which states that an invariant form on $G/K$ is automatically closed (and harmonic). Indeed, we can combine this last isomorphism with the isomorphisms mentioned in the second paragraph to conclude that
$$ \Omega^q(G/H)^G = (\wedge^q \mathfrak h^\perp)^H $$
and both are isomorphic to the cohomology of the complex of $G$-invariant forms on $G/H$.

In general we can't deduce from this that the cohomology of $G/H$ is isomorphic to $(\wedge^\ast \mathfrak h^\perp)^H$, because not every closed form will necessarily have an invariant form in its cohomology class. However, if $G$ is compact, then this is not a problem, because we can use the usual averaging trick.

Anyway, the point of introducing Lie algebra cohomology into the picture is that it makes things very [computable](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DifferentialGeometry/LessonsAndTutorials/Tutorials/LieAlgebraCohomology). It will also be an important key phrase for any literature search.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think I do mean the Levi-Civita connection and not a Laplacian.  At least for $G$ compact, isn't any harmonic form necessarily $G$ invariant and for a symmetric space any invariant form is parallel.   I will look into using that Maple package, though I'm still wondering if there's a list out describing $\Lambda^* \mathfrak h^\perp)^H$ for a large class of examples.

Comment: Each cohomology class has a unique harmonic representative by deRham. But under the action of the group $G$, since $G$ is connected, the cohomology class of a harmonic form is unchanged by $G$ action. Therefore the harmonic representative is $G$-invariant. I can't remember if that ensures that it is parallel.