# Closed Invariant Forms on Complex Projective $k$-Space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cohomology

Considering complex projective $k$-space as the homogeneous space $SU_k/U_{k-1}$, is it true that every $SU_k$-invariant form is closed?

Comment: Citing from the master: http://mathoverflow.net/a/158565/21123

Comment: So yes, complex projective space is a symmetric space and its invariant forms are harmonic and, therefore, closed.